# Make outgoing call with CallKit

Tags: swift2, callkit

I'm actually on swift 2.3.
Inbound Call works great with CallKit. But OutGoing Call ....

I saw the SpeakerBox project, I do the same things.
But it doesn't work.

To start my call, I used

```
let handle = CXHandle(type: .PhoneNumber, value: "TOTO")
let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(callUUID: uuid, handle: handle)
startCallAction.video = video
let transaction = CXTransaction()
transaction.addAction(startCallAction)
requestTransaction(transaction)
```

After, in SpeakerBox Project, this function is called :

```
func provider(provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction)
```

But not in my project. Then, when i hangup, i see : "Call failed".

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: "Call Failed" often indicates that your own app has crashed, can you tell in the debugger if your app is crashing?

Comment: Are you doing this on a device and not simulator? Did you add the voip background mode? Did you initialize your provider properly?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are configuring your CXProvider and setting its delegate properly. If you do not set the CXProvider's `delegate` property, the delegate will not receive any actions to perform.

Also, if you see a "Call Failed" UI, this may indicate your app is crashing. I'd check for crash logs or run the app in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, SpeakerBox demo does not perform the following provider method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxprovider/1930701-reportcall

```
func reportCall(with UUID: UUID, 
        endedAt dateEnded: Date?, 
         reason endedReason: CXCallEndedReason)
```

---

```
- (void)reportCallWithUUID:(NSUUID *)UUID endedAtDate:(nullable NSDate 
*)dateEnded reason:(CXCallEndedReason)endedReason;
```

Which leads to the "Call failed" UI screen being displayed - as CallKit was not given a reason why the call has ended, and it seems that "
CXCallEndedReasonFailed" is assumed by default.

Call "reportCall endedAt" before requesting the CXEndCallAction transaction to remove "Call failed" screen.

Comment: Even adding this in, we still see the "Call Failed". When we add this in, we also see the CXEndCallAction transaction error out -
Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 (which is unknownCallUUID).
Do we need to make sure to make this call asynchronously, or as part of handling the call end action in the Provider Delegate?

Comment: If you receive the error "Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 (which is unknownCallUUID)", you are passing unknown UUID to "reportCallWithUUID" method. Make sure you are using the same call UUID  as your actual call

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the required permissions to your info.plist?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate. action.fulfill() will make sure you do not see call failed.

```
public func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
    action.fulfill() 
}
```